# Compilation Error with Solc - Solc Error: dyld[30112]: Library not loaded: '/opt/homebrew/opt/z3/lib/libz3.dylib'

Tags: solc

I recently updated my solc to the latest version for foundry testing and contract compilation. I have an M1 mac and I am using Mac OS Monteray 12.5
Suddenly I am getting an error when trying to use solc

```
Error: 
Solc Error: dyld[30112]: Library not loaded: '/opt/homebrew/opt/z3/lib/libz3.dylib'
  Referenced from: '/Users/katejohnson/.svm/0.8.15/solc-0.8.15'
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/z3/lib/libz3.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libz3.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (x86_64), need (arm64e))), '/usr/lib/libz3.dylib' (no such file)
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with foundry and was resolved with recent "foundryup"